# Reformatting $y$-axis labels from decimal to exponential form

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

I have this graphic

[image]

How can I reformat 0.001 as 10^-3? just like the 10^-4?

Comment: You may want to use the `Ticks` option.  Or, you may want to use `FrameTicks`, which has a different syntax.  Also, you might to search this site for something like "tick  exponent" to get some useful ideas.  If you have trouble implementing one of the previous answers, please edit your question to include the actual code you are running, so that we can duplicate your plot and suggest a solution.

Comment: you are the best!i searched for ticks and frameticks and this works like a charm!THANKS!